# AWS Batch - Container override - How to pass a sequence of statements

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I am running my first batch job through console using amazon/linux as my image.

Docker image has command set as CMD "/bin/bash"
How do I pass a script through command override during Job submission.

When I pass command as **yum -y install unzip aws-cli --aws s3 ls** I get an error also I tried using **&&** no luck. How do I combine multiple statements and pass via command override to run it in a sequence ?

Appreciate some ones help.

Comment: It sounds like you need to brush up some more on `docker` before you tackle `Batch`

Answer (score 0):

I think this sort of thing is better suited to being either in the build stage of your Docker container by using `RUN` commands, which is good for installing things or wrapped up into a single script and added into your docker image using the `COPY` command in the dockerfile.